# Approximate root of $\alpha x - \beta y$ over $\mathbb Z$ except origin

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

Consider the polynomial $ f(x,y) = \alpha x^2 - \beta y^2 $

**Prove or disprove:** For any choice of $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R_0^+$, the polynomial $f$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ over $\mathbb Z \setminus (0,0)$

This obviously true for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being square numbers.

Comment: I assume you're not allowing $x=y=0$.  Have you tried, say,  $\alpha = 1, \beta=2$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good hint.

Comment: Has been a late night. Of course, the origin is excluded.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you give more hints? I have no clue where to start with this.

Comment: If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $x$ and $y$ are integers, $f(x,y)$ is an integer.  It it can't be $0$, it can't be close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we have
$$
|f(x,y)| < \epsilon \iff\\
\left|\alpha x^2 - \beta y^2\right| < \epsilon \iff\\
\left|\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - \frac{y^2}{x^2}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{\beta x^2}
$$

Comment: Assuming $\beta > 0$, I see the equivalences. But what does it tell?

Comment: You can handle the case where either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is zero separately without too much work.  What I'm heading towards is the following: if $y^2/x^2$ is a sufficiently good approximation of $\alpha/\beta$, then $f(x,y)$ will be correspondingly close to zero.  Thus, we've reduced the question to finding rational approximations $y/x$ of $\sqrt{\alpha/\beta}$.